# Displaying probability values in correct format

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I am get very small value for probability. I applied this logic to see the result in % format

```
n = ((pprob + nprob)/pprob)*100
p = ((pprob + nprob)/nprob)*100
```

but still n and p goes out of 100.

For some of the case results are as below:

```
Positive prob :  0.000129871739341
Negative prob :  7.10856195823e-05
Positive :  282.697625911
Negative :  154.735248749
Please enter the sentence : hate
Positive prob :  1.25452951182e-05
Negative prob :  1.67051206018e-05
Positive :  175.098500736
Negative :  233.158450594
Please enter the sentence : nice
Positive prob :  4.2613370867e-05
Negative prob :  3.40195465144e-05
Positive :  225.261431245
Negative :  179.833033206
Please enter the sentence : bad
Positive prob :  5.32794112508e-05
Negative prob :  0.000182233063343
Positive :  129.236961874
Negative :  442.032802287
```

code is:

```
for word in words:
    pp = (pos[word] + 1) / (2 * totals[0])
    np = (neg[word] + 1) / (2 * totals[1])
    #print "%15s %.9f %.9f" % (word, exp(pp), exp(np))
    pprob += pp
    nprob += np
    # print pp, ", ", np
print "Positive prob : ", pprob
print "Negative prob : ", nprob
n = ((pprob + nprob)/pprob)*100
p = ((pprob + nprob)/nprob)*100
print "Positive : ", p
print "Negative : ", n
```

Any good way to display `p and n` in % format, where result should be withing 100.

Comment: You're dividing a number by something smaller than it, so you should be expecting to get numbers larger than 100 after multiplying by 100. I think you want pprob/(pprob+nprob)*100 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pprob` and `nprob` are both positive, then of course
`(pprob + nprob)/pprob` will be greater than $1$, since
$$\frac{x + y}{x} = 1 + \frac yx.$$

On the other hand, `pprob/(pprob + nprob)` and `nprob/(pprob + nprob)`
will each be less than $1$, and
`pprob/(pprob + nprob) + nprob/(pprob + nprob)`
will equal $1$ (or nearly so, depending on rounding and truncation errors).

So perhaps you are looking for
`100 * pprob/(pprob + nprob)` and `100 * nprob/(pprob + nprob)`.

Answer (score 1):

Define $n = \frac{\text{nprob}}{\text{nprob}+\text{pprob}}$ 
similarly, $p = \frac{\text{pprob}}{\text{nprob}+\text{pprob}}$

This way $p+n$ = 1 and you can calculate the percentage which will be less than 100. Important thing you missed is that any probability $0 \leq p \leq 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 1$ where $i={1,2,...n}$ represent mutually exclusive events covering the entire event space.